# Babel build vs webpack babel-loader build

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

index.js

```
import Colors from "./colors";
module.exports = {
  Colors
};
```

colors.js

```
module.exports = {
  // light shades
  white: "#FFFFFF",
  snow: "#F9FAFC",
  darkSnow: "#EFF2F7",
  extraDarkSnow: "#E5E9F2",
  // dark tones
  silver: "#8492A6",
  slate: "#3C4858"
}
```

After running the babel cli 'babel lib -d build'
Output is :
index.js

```
"use strict";

var _colors = require("./colors");

var _colors2 = _interopRequireDefault(_colors);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

module.exports = {
  Colors: _colors2.default
};
```

colors.js

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  // light shades
  white: "#FFFFFF",
  snow: "#F9FAFC",
  darkSnow: "#EFF2F7",
  extraDarkSnow: "#E5E9F2",
  // dark tones
  silver: "#8492A6",
  slate: "#3C4858",
  steel: "#273444"
}
```

But when using the webpack loader,output is

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "/";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";


var _colors = __webpack_require__(1);

var _colors2 = _interopRequireDefault(_colors);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

module.exports = {
  Colors: _colors2.default
};

/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";


module.exports = {
  // light shades
  white: "#FFFFFF",
  snow: "#F9FAFC",
  darkSnow: "#EFF2F7",
  extraDarkSnow: "#E5E9F2",
  // dark tones
  silver: "#8492A6",
  slate: "#3C4858",
  steel: "#273444",
  black: "#1F2D3D"
}
```

So my question here is, Why webpack is adding extra code to my bundle. 
Is webpack bundle code is similar to my babel output code?

Comment: All Webpack is doing is first *using Babel* to transpile your ES6 to ES5. With that Babel output, it wraps it in some IIFEs and such for the web.

Answer (score 0):

`webpack` has its own way to keep track of dependencies and actually bundle the file.
One key difference is that each module in `webpack`'s bundle will be wrapped in individual function closures (maybe that is what you are referring to, this "extra" code?).
`webpack` v3 is released a few days ago and support a new feature `Scope Hoisting`, this feature address the exact behavior mentioned above.
From the [DOCS](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-3-official-release-15fd2dd8f07b#c11e):

> Scope Hoisting is the flagship feature of webpack 3. One of webpack’s
>   trade-offs when bundling was that each module in your bundle would be
>   wrapped in individual function closures. These wrapper functions made
>   it slower for your JavaScript to execute in the browser. In
>   comparison, tools like Closure Compiler and RollupJS ‘hoist’ or
>   concatenate the scope of all your modules into one closure and allow
>   for your code to have a faster execution time in the browser...

This is the relevant part for the file size

> Because scope hoisting will remove function wrappers around your
>   modules, you may see some small size improvements. However, the
>   significant improvement will be how fast the JavaScript loads in the
>   browser...